# Android local voice service

Tags: android

As we all know, you can use an Android phone to dial a number to make a phone call.

Is there any way using the Android SDK to dial a number, but connected to a service running locally on the device?

My aim is to create some sort of interactive voice service (running locally on the phone), that could be used with bluetooth device that only support making phone calls...

My back up plan would be to run an Asterisk server in the house to handle this, but it would be nice to have something running on the phone instead.

Thanks